# dask jobs hangs indefinitely and inconsistently

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I am running multiple concurrent dask jobs using dask-client submit api. It have come across this issue multiple times.

Thread dump of the specific worker shows below information.

Can some one guide me about this problem.

```
ts_data = dask_df[key].values.compute()
  File "/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 135, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
  File "/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 333, in compute
    results = get(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File "/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1999, in get
    results = self.gather(packed, asynchronous=asynchronous)
  File "/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1437, in gather
    asynchronous=asynchronous)
  File "/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 592, in sync
    return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 252, in sync
    e.wait(1000000)
  File "/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 551, in wait
    signaled = self._cond.wait(timeout)
  File "/agent/miniconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 299, in wait
    gotit = waiter.acquire(True, timeout)
```

Comment: I recommend trying to create a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sure MR. I will create and post one MCVE .